# Changing the styles of MobileTimePicker from MUI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am attempting to change the style of bordeqr, text of the input field, labels and the line that lets you choose the time(screenshots) for this time picker. I have managed to change the default style for the label and border, but can't change it for when the field is focused, it is currently showing the default color - blue for both border and label.
The part of the code:

```
'&:focus-within': {
                  color: '#6750a4',
                  borderColor: 'red'
                },
```

DOES NOT WORK.

[image: focused timepicker field]
[image]

```
import { LocalizationProvider, roRO } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
import { AdapterDayjs } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs';
import "dayjs/locale/ro";

import { MobileTimePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';



const TimePickerOne = ({ onChange }: { onChange: () => void }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale='ro'>
        <MobileTimePicker
          sx={{
            ".MuiFormLabel-root": {
              color: '#49454F'
            },
            ".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": {
                borderColor: '#49454F',
                '&:focus-within': {
                  color: '#6750a4',
                  borderColor: 'red'
                },
            }
          }}
          label="Ora"
          disablePast
          orientation='portrait'
          minutesStep={30}
          reduceAnimations
          onChange={onChange}
          localeText={{
            cancelButtonLabel: 'Anulează',
            okButtonLabel: "OK",
            toolbarTitle: 'Alege o oră disponibilă'
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </div>
  )
}

export default TimePickerOne
```